# how to fix Unity WebGL issue using useUnityContext in React

Tags: html, reactjs, unity-game-engine

Could you tell me why I have got this issue? This issue happened when I clicked another tab.
Also, I can't send messages from React to Unity. The first time it's running well but next time after refresh can't send a message.

https://www.loom.com/share/b00171cc56664d1082db196a60eecabe

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import { Unity, useUnityContext } from "react-unity-webgl";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useEthers } from "@usedapp/core";
import axios from "axios";
import Button from "./Button";

const API_URL = "http://XXXXXXXXXX";

const theCrew = [3, 4, 5, 6];

const StyledLicense = styled.div`
  padding: 0 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: var(--bg-02);

  @media (max-width: 720px) {
    padding: 2rem;
    padding-top: 7rem;
  }
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 150em;
`;

const Loading = styled.h1`
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--sub);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;

  font-size: 2.4rem;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
`;
const Fullscreen = styled.h1`
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fb006d;
  cursor:pointer;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
`;

const CyberRunner = () => {
  const { activateBrowserWallet, deactivate, account } = useEthers();
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState();
  const {
    unityProvider,
    loadingProgression,
    isLoaded,
    addEventListener,
    removeEventListener,
    requestFullscreen,
    sendMessage
  } = useUnityContext({
    loaderUrl: "Kiwi/Build/Kiwi.loader.js",
    dataUrl: "Kiwi/Build/Kiwi.data",
    frameworkUrl: "Kiwi/Build/Kiwi.framework.js",
    codeUrl: "Kiwi/Build/Kiwi.wasm",
    streamingAssetsUrl: "Kiwi/StreamingAssets",
  });

  const connectWallet = useCallback(() => {
    if (!account)
      activateBrowserWallet();
    else
      getRecord();
  }, [account]);

  const disconnectWallet = useCallback(() => {
    if (!account)
      deactivate();
    else
      sendMessage("LoginController", "SetDisconnectWallet");
  }, [account])
  const setRecord = useCallback((_distance: number, _kill: number) => {
    axios.post(API_URL + "/api/record/setRecord", {
      user_id: userId,
      distance: _distance,
      kill: _kill
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  }, [userId])

  const getRecord = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(API_URL + "/api/auth/joingame", {
      wallet_address: account
    });
    axios.post(API_URL + "/api/auth/joingame", {
      wallet_address: account
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.userId);
        setUserId(res.data.userId);
        axios.get(API_URL + "/api/record/getRecord")
          .then(records => {
            sendMessage("LoginController", "SetHistory", JSON.stringify(records.data));
          });
      });
  }, [account]);

  useEffect(() => {
    addEventListener("ReactSetRecord", setRecord);
    addEventListener("DisconnectWallet", disconnectWallet);
    addEventListener("ConnectWallet", connectWallet);
    return () => {
      removeEventListener("ReactSetRecord", setRecord);
      removeEventListener("ConnectWallet", connectWallet);
      removeEventListener("DisconnectWallet", disconnectWallet);
    };
  }, [addEventListener, removeEventListener, connectWallet, disconnectWallet, setRecord, account]);

  return (
    <StyledLicense>
      {!isLoaded && (
        <Loading>Loading Application... {Math.round(loadingProgression * 100)}%</Loading>
      )}
      <Content>
        <Unity unityProvider={unityProvider} style={{ width: 1280, height: 720 }} />
      </Content>
      <Button text="Fullscreen" click={() => requestFullscreen(true)} primary />
      <Footer />
    </StyledLicense>
  );
};

export default CyberRunner;
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to help with data collection.

I'm still testing sending messages, I can't help much for now.

My bridge to bring in the data uses "window.addEventListener", but keep in mind that I added a custom event directly to "window" in my unity C# file.

For example:

```
    public void SendScoreEvent(int score)
    {
        // JSON with score
        string eventData = "{\"score\":" + score.ToString() + "}";

        // call JavaScript function
        Application.ExternalEval("window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ScoreEvent', { detail: " + eventData + " }));");
    }
```

hook and handle function:

```
  function handleScore(event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("ScoreEvent", handleScore);
    

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("ScoreEvent", handleScore);
          
};
  }, [Unity]);
```

Remove 'addEventListener" and "removeEventListener":

```
const {
    unityProvider,
    loadingProgression,
    isLoaded,
    requestFullscreen,
    sendMessage,
  } = useUnityContext({
    loaderUrl: "/buildUnit/WebGL.loader.js",
    dataUrl: "/buildUnit/WebGL.data",
    frameworkUrl: "/buildUnit/WebGL.framework.js",
    codeUrl: "/buildUnit/WebGL.wasm",
  })
```